# Is it possible to check whether a script of any version has been included?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting, include, greasemonkey

Earlier this day I wrote a small script for `greasemonkey` which fixes the sometimes buggy auto scroll in the StackOverflow Chat.

I did `// @require jquery.........` however that lead to some problems since the chat is already using jQuery in a lower version which is not compatible with a newer version since a couple of functions are deprecated or have been removed.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        StackOverflowChat
// @namespace   deW1.net
// @include     http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/*
// @require     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

$( document ).ready( function( )
{
    setInterval( function( )
    {
        $( "html , body" ).animate( 
        {
            scrollTop: $( document ).height( )
        } );
    } , 5000 );
} );
```

Now the question is can I somehow check whether jQuery is already included in the webpage of any version so I don't `@require`it again.

This is mainly for scripts which are applicable to many different websites without me knowing which are running which jQuery version.

( I took jQuery as an example, basically it could be any library )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just check to see if `jQuery` exists?

```
if ( typeof jQuery !== 'function') {
  // load jQuery
} 
// do other stuff here
```

Comment: Also, you can get the version of jQuery that's loaded using `$.fn.jquery`

Answer (score 0):

This is possible only with an AMD architecture.

In a situation in wich libraries are included into the page without any Dependency Injection system, this condition can't be checked in an elegant way.

However you can crete an algorithm that checks all the included scripts. It can do this by using any kind of method like regexp or data-attr inserted into script tags.